# my hp laptop show red cross on wifi icon please help me

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

How to fix the problem of red cross in my laptop windows7
It show that wireless capability is turned off, what i can do
In adapter setting in driver it show red cross
Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you hit the "airplane mode" switch.

Since I am not sure, what your pc model is, then it is on the right side, left or even the front side. Try to find it. It normally is a slide switch (so it can be left or right) if you find it, flip it and the wifi should work again.

Let me know of any updates.